# PyInstaller no me deja abrir una aplicación

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, windows10, pyinstaller

Practicando interfaces gráficas con `Tkinter` en Python, cree una calculadora. Luego, instalé `pyinstaller` para convertir el archivo en un aplicación, con extensión `.exe`.

Y una vez que quiero abrir el archivo, Windows (10 de 64-bit) me envía un error diciendo esto:

```
Existen recursos de sistema insuficientes para completar el servicio solicitado
```

Por lo que no me permite abrir el la aplicación de la calculadora que cree. Tampoco se que significa este error.

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

Ya intente abrirlo cuando mientras no tenía ningún otro programa o aplicación abierto, y reiniciando la laptop, pero sigue marcándome ese error.

También desinstalé y volví a instalar `PyInstaller`, y la aplicación creada, pero tampoco funciona.

Gracias, y saludos.

Comment: Hola. como lo estas empaquetando ? 

Al ejecutarlo en el IDE si te ejecuta el programa?

Comment: En el IDE o editor de texto, sea cual sea que use, en este caso, VS Code/Sublime Text 3/Spyder, si me ejecutan el programa

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar como alternativa de pyinstaller la librería auto-py-to-exe

https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/

Ahí están todas las instrucciones

Espero haberte ayudado